# Simple form: has_many through check boxes nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

i faced similar to this problem before but this time i cannot solve it, i did a lot of searching here and google but i cannot find the same situation i am facing here

I have 3 models , student , subject, attend, each time i try to assign a student to many subjects through attend form , `subject_id` saved as `null` in case of using `check_boxes`, i tried using `f.association :subject` but its giving the same result , also there is an empty value inside the array `"attend"=>{"student_id"=>"1", "subject_id"=>["1", "2", ""]}}` and  here is my code

student.rb

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :gender, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :attends
  has_many :subjects, :through => :attends

  def full_name
    "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
  end
end
```

subject.rb

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :subject_title, :subjectCode
  has_many :attends
  has_many :students, :through => :attends
end
```

attend.rb

```
class Attend < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :student_id, :subject_id
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :subject
end
```

attends/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@attend) do |f| %>
              <%= f.association :student, as: :select, label_method: :full_name, prompt: 'Select Student' %>
              <%= f.input :subject_id, collection:@subjects, as: :check_boxes,label_method: :subject_title, value_method: :id %>
              <% end %>
```

attends_controller.rb

```
class AttendsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @attends = Attend.all
  end

  def show
    @attend = Attend.find(params[:id])

  end

  def new
    @attend = Attend.new
    @subjects = Subject.all
  end

  def create
    @attend = Attend.new(params[:attend])
    if @attend.save
      redirect_to attends_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @attend = Attend.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @attend = Attend.find(params[:id])
    if @attend.update_attributes(params[:attend])
      redirect_to attends_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @attend = Attend.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

server development log

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8Z9LTJbYpNnFtvLKs4MpO2pongrKmFkSIz0jzxcuQH0=", "attend"=>{"student_id"=>"1", "subject_id"=>["1", "2", ""]}}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "attends" ("created_at", "student_id", "subject_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sat, 14 Dec 2013 11:34:02 UTC +00:00], ["student_id", 1], ["subject_id", nil], ["updated_at", Sat, 14 Dec 2013 11:34:02 UTC +00:00]]
   (169.6ms)  commit transaction
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save intermediate relationship, with simple form. In your controller create method, @attend is intended for saving only one record. But you are trying to input many subjects there. The problem came there only.